# Pandas groupby on one column and then filter based on quantile value of another column

Tags: pandas

I am trying to filter my data down to only those rows in the bottom decile of the data for any given date.  Thus, I need to groupby the date first to get the sub-universe of data and then from there filter that same sub-universe down to only those values falling in the bottom decile.  I then need to aggregate all of the different dates back together to make one large dataframe.

For example, I want to take the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2017-01-01', 1], ['2017-01-01', 5], ['2017-01-01', 10], ['2018-01-01', 5], ['2018-01-01', 10]], columns=['date', 'value'])
```

and only those rows where the value is in the bottom decile for that date (below 1.8 and 5.5, respectively):

```
       date       value
0  '2017-01-01'     1
1  '2018-01-01'     5
```

I can get a series of the bottom decile using `df.groupby(['date'], 'value'].quantile(.1)`, but this would then require me to iterate through the entire df and compare the value to the quantile value in the series, which I'm trying to avoid due to performance issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
df.groupby('date').value.apply(lambda x: x[x < x.quantile(.1)]).reset_index(1,drop = True).reset_index()

    date        value
0   2017-01-01      1
1   2018-01-01      5
```

Edit:

```
df.loc[df['value'] < df.groupby('date').value.transform(lambda x: x.quantile(.1))]
```

Comment: This completes the functionality, but due to the use of .apply effectively is looping through the dataframe, which will cause performance problems in practice.  I'm hoping to find a solution that is more efficient than looping if possible.

Comment: @cstainbrook, fair point. Try the edit, its testing better on the dummy dataset, would be interesting to see the result on larger set

Comment: Yeah, that looks good and is about 50% faster on the larger data, which is a nice improvement.  Thanks for the help!